# Groovy class with multiple fields showing only one field - public static transient boolean C.__$stMC

Tags: groovy, metaclass

I was trying to use the method `getFields()` on a simple dummy class as follows:

```
class C{
  public int a
  int b
  String s
  float f
  static int x
}
```

I wrote

```
def c = new C()
println c.class.getFields()
```

This is what I got as output:

```
[public int C.a, public static transient boolean C.__$stMC]
```

Can someone explain why only `a` appears in the list?
And what is the other entity `C.__$stMC`? 
I searched online, seems stMC represents staticMetaClass. Please clarify. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because as per the documentation, getFields() returns the public fields only:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields()

Either use getDeclaredFields() or use the Groovy meta programming properties i.e:

```
def c = new C()
println c.class.getDeclaredFields().toString()
println c.getProperties().toString()
```

Comment: But in Groovy, all fields are public be default. So, `getFields() ` should include those too, isn't it?
Also, any idea about $stMC? What does it stand for?

Comment: All fields have public access modifiers. When you change the value using obj.prop = "x", underneath the hood it is actually calling a method. Under the compiled java field is not public.